# dd show 'raw' progress while piping output

Tags: bash, dd, gzip

I am attempting to perform a specific dd operation and appending 'raw' data of the transfer to a log file which will be polled by something else, to provide a live view of the transfer on another interface (i.e. not terminal).

The dd operation is:

`dd if=/some/lvm bs=512K | gzip -c > /tmp/whatever`

The simplest way I can see is to output that command to a file and kill -SIGUSR1 pid simultaneously and view the output although I cannot find a way to store the pid of the process in a variable and use it in the kill command.

I've seen this <strike>one</strike> two liner around:

`dd if=/some/lvm of=/some/fat/image/which/I/cant/use bs=512K& pid=$!; \

  sleep 1; while [[ -d /proc/$pid ]]; do kill -USR1 $pid && sleep 1; done`

Although I don't particularly understand how it pulls the pid as a variable so I can't modify it to work with my piped output.

I am happy looking at alternatives to dd, although the most just give even more complication such as dcfldd which updates the same line though some, I presume curses-like method. That makes it hard to pull a snapshot of that output each second and pull the data I need. If there's an easy way I can deal with that or even piping to pv if I can get the output 'raw'.

Please enlighten me. ;-)

Regards

EDIT: So I've found a "solution", it's still not pretty but

I can use pgrep to find a process id, so while the dd command is running and outputted to a file, I'd run `watch -n1 'sudo kill -USR1 $(pgrep ^dd)'` to output progress on the transfer every second which can be interpreted by the poller.

It's still not an elegant solution, and feels like a bodge. If there's a better way I'm still open to suggestions. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The best answer is `pv`, which lets you see progress for any process you can pipe.

```
dd if=/some/lvm bs=512K | pv | gzip -c > /tmp/whatever
```

You can even use this for your typical `dd` usage of creating or writing disk images by piping `dd` to itself via `pv`:

```
dd if=/dev/cdrom | pv | dd of=/path/to/some.iso
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, but the output of pv isn't easy to interpret by an external poller. That's my question, may not have been clear, but I need something that gives me raw data or a method of extracting that.

Comment: `pv -n` will give output that is farily easily parseable rather than a progress bar.

Comment: Those `dd` are pointless. Just use `</some/lvm pv | pigz > /tmp/whatever.gz` (add `-B 512K` if you want `pv` to make 512K large reads for whatever reason)

Comment: The `dd` invocations in the answer are to make the thrust of the answer distinct in the context of the example in the OP, which was framed around the use of `dd`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a single script that should accomplish the goal:

```
(
        dd if=/some/lvm bs=512K &
        pid_dd=$!

        while :; do
                sleep 1
                kill -USR1 $pid_dd
        done &
        pid_monitor=$!

        wait $pid_dd
        kill $pid_monitor
) |
        gzip -c > /tmp/whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

For the interest of those that might still stumble onto this:

If you want to grep or process the progress from dd, you can wrap some brackets around it. Since the output triggered by the kill goes to stderr, you can redirect 2>&1 to make it e.g. greppable:

```
# ( DP=$(
 dd if=/proc/kcore of=/dev/null bs=1M count=50000 &
 echo $!);  while kill -USR1 $DP 2>/dev/null; do sleep 1; done ) 2>&1 |grep copied
0 bytes copied, 1.73e-05 s, 0.0 kB/s
21043871744 bytes (21 GB, 20 GiB) copied, 1.01827 s, 20.7 GB/s
42920312832 bytes (43 GB, 40 GiB) copied, 2.02764 s, 21.2 GB/s
52428800000 bytes (52 GB, 49 GiB) copied, 2.49048 s, 21.1 GB/s
#
```

Adding the zip makes it interesting - we will need more brackets! Since we will need to detour via >&3 to leave >&1 clear for gzip:

```
    # ZIPFILE=/path/to/zipfile..
    # ( DP=$(
((dd if=/proc/kcore bs=1M count=500 & echo $! >&3 ) | gzip > $ZIPFILE & ) 3>&1|head -1); 
    sleep 1 # wait for dd startup; 
    while kill -USR1 $DP 2>/dev/null ; do sleep 1; done) 2>&1|grep copied
    241172480 bytes (241 MB, 230 MiB) copied, 1.00001 s, 241 MB/s
    486539264 bytes (487 MB, 464 MiB) copied, 2.00568 s, 243 MB/s
    524288000 bytes (524 MB, 500 MiB) copied, 2.16047 s, 243 MB/s
```

Modify the dd to suit your purpose.

PS. This belongs in a wrapper script, with the |grep or whatever then moved outside of the script. Or going the opposite way, it all works just as well on one line :-)

Comment: But the question is about `dd … | gzip`. How would you capture the PID of `dd` when its output is being piped? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Fair point - added another bit to work with piped dd output too

Comment: Wow! *`( program₁ & ) | program₂`* kind-of blows my mind.  And, if I’m not mistaken, you’re actually using that construct twice in that script.  But I guess it’ll work.  However, I believe that there’s a smallish (?) problem: your script will exit one second after `dd` terminates — but the `gzip` might still be running asynchronously.

Comment: Yup, worst case there could be no wait at all for the gzip to wrap up. If it's a concern, you could replace the gzip with a script that includes any post-processing, or gzip to a temporary filename or folder and then only rename to the final name when done - which could then be checked for.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use `pv`, you're on the right track with `kill -USR1`.  Given your initial command of `dd if=/some/lvm bs=512K | gzip -c > /tmp/whatever`, I would do something like this withing the context of a pair of scripts:

```
dd if=/some/lvm bs=512K | gzip -c > /tmp/whatever &
PID=$! # $! is set to the PID of the last backgrounded process
echo $PID > /var/run/dd_pid.txt  # So that other scripts can read it
fg
rm /var/run/dd_pid.txt
```

Meanwhile, in your other script:

```
PID=$(cat /var/run/dd_pid.txt)
if [[ 0 -ne $? ]]; then
    echo 'PID file not found'
    exit 1
fi
while kill -0 $PID; do
    sleep 1
    kill -USR1 $PID
done
```

Comment: `$!` will be `gzip`'s pid. `kill -USR1 $PID` will kill `gzip` and`dd`'s next write will trigger a SIGPIPE and `dd`'s premature demise.